# Kubernetes: "unauthorized". can't figure out how to get authenticated

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

So, i'm trying to work with kubernetes (minikube). I'm a total beginner, with some basic experience with docker.
It turns out, i installed kubernetes 2 days ago and haven't managed to do a single thing.
I barely managed to connect to the dashboard, and spent an ungodly amount of time finding how to get authenticated for that.

All i'm trying to do is to deploy a single docker image but I can't even do a basic hello world tutorial, as pretty much whatever command i type, i get an error message about not being authorized.

At the moment, I'm trying to write a deployment file, but i'm getting this "unauthorized" error as soon as i use "kubectl create".  I'm totally at a loss as to what to do.

**kubectl create -f deployment.yaml**

```
error: unable to recognize "deployment.yaml": Unauthorized
```

I don't know what information to give you. Here is the minikube status:

**minikube status**

```
host: Running
kubelet: Running
apiserver: Running
kubectl: Correctly Configured: pointing to minikube-vm at 192.168.99.100
```

**Minikube version** : v1.2.0

**Docker version** :  18.06.3-ce, build d7080c1

**kubectl version** :

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.0", GitCommit:"e8462b5b5dc2584fdcd18e6bcfe9f1e4d970a529", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-06-19T16:40:16Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.0", GitCommit:"e8462b5b5dc2584fdcd18e6bcfe9f1e4d970a529", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-06-19T16:32:14Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Do you guys have any idea what to do? The issue here is really that i don't understand what is happening:
- Why do i need to authenticate?
- What do i need to authenticate myself against?
- Why is it not self evident what to do?

I find that most pages about the topic online are either outdated, or ask me to perform action that just end up returning "enable to recognize ... : Unauthorized". The tutorials online don't address this problem. They all seem to automatically be able to use "kubectl create" without any need for authentication.

Do you know what i'm supposed to do? Have you had this problem?

Comment: in api service configuration(probably inside /etc/kubernetes/apiserver) look for KUBE_ADMISSION_CONTROL. Comment this line and restart API server, this is to test if you are blocked at this level.

Comment: Hi @ShubhamSingh, i actually don't have a /etc/kubernetes folder. I noticed that some people where sometimes referencing it, but i don't have it. I'm not too sure where that kubernetes directory is. I have ~/.kube and ~/.minikube .

Comment: Have you tried using the minikube embedded  kubectl? `minikube kubectl create -f deploy.yaml`. Also, check that the current context is correctly set in kubectl? `minikube update-context`?

Comment: @YahirHernández, `minikube update-context` says that minikube IP is already correctly configured.`minikube kubectl cluster-info` says "downloading kubectl v1.15.0", but then outputs `error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by deleting ~/.kube and removing the minikube and kubectl binaries at /usr/local/bin.

I re-downloaded and re-installed minikube and kubectl. I then launched `minikube start`, and everything is now working fine.

The origin of my problem seem to have been the installation of the dashboard. I followed some indications online, not knowing exactly what i was doing. In the process, i had to create some security roles, and something involving a token. I managed to connect to the dashboard, but from then on, every kubectl command told me that i was unauthorized.